# How to compile ffmpeg and x264 with thread support for android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, x264

i want to compile both x264 and ffmpeg with thread support for ANDROID .FFmpeg and x264 didn't compile with thread support even after enabling enable-pthreads and  enable-threads respectively.

Both the config.h contains #define HAVE_THREAD 0 and #define HAVE_PTHREADS 0

1.How to compile with thread support.
2.Second question is that when i increase the gop size from 1 to some other value encoder returns 0 for certain subsequent frames.This causes a delay more than 3 to 5 seconds in vide playing

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NDK9 standalone toolchain cross compile the last x264 library with thread support.

Here is my step.
http://bashell.nodemedia.cn/archives/cross-complie-pthread-android-x264-library.html

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, maybe looking at how configure checks whether pthreads are supported is a good place to start? I saw a patch to autotools machinery in x264 that might help: http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/x264-devel/2012-April/009309.html

Comment: hi is that anything i can do with configuration script.

Comment: This is free open source software not working the way you want it to work. What you about this is one of: (1) fix it, (2) pay someone to fix it, or (3) wait for someone to fix it for themselves and contribute the fix back upstream, because they share your needs and are nice. Did you try applying the patch? Did you look at the test for pthreads and why it fails? If you are unable or unwilling to do (1) or (2), do (3).

Answer (score 0):

See my patch for **x264** here: https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/x264-devel/2013-March/009941.html

These two easy steps will also work for **ffmpeg**